# Redirects to broken url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I wrote code that checks if the user has all required information in DB or not. If the user has, do nothing, but if they are empty redirect to `continueregistration` page. But when it redirects it writes that

> This page isn’t working
>
> localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I cleared my cache it did not work. Here is my view:

```
<?php 

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('instructors', array('id' => $this->session->userdata('id'))); 

    $insdatacheck = $query->row_array();

    if($insdatacheck['name'] == '') {
      redirect('/user/continueregistration/');
    } else { ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>
      <?php
    }

    }

?>
```

and controller:

```
function continueregistration() {

        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[2]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('web', 'web adress', 'trim|required|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('facebook', 'facebook adress', 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('twitter', 'twitter adress', 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('youtube', 'youtube adress', 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('instagram', 'instagram adress', 'trim|valid_url|prep_url|min_length[3]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tel', 'telephone number', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'address', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('insdescription', 'description', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric_spaces|min_length[3]'); 

        $data['title'] = 'Continue Registration';
        $data['instructors'] = $this->single_instructor_model->get_instructor_info();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('registration/registration', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        //validate form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // fails
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('registration/registration', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            //insert the user registration details into database
            $dataforreg = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'web' => $this->input->post('web'),
                'fb' => $this->input->post('facebook'),
                'twitter' => $this->input->post('twitter'),
                'youtube' => $this->input->post('youtube'),
                'instagram' => $this->input->post('instagram'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('tel'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('insdescription')
            );

            // insert form data into database
            if ($this->user_model->updateUser($dataforreg, $to_email)) {
                    redirect('homepage/index');

            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error</div>');
                    redirect('user/continueregistration');
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: it means you have a loop of redirects

Comment: In what view do you have that code? It should really be in a controller instead. though. A view is purely for presentation. No business logic or flow control should ever be in a view.

Comment: you are calling continueregistration inside continueregistration

Comment: @inarilo where i call it?

Comment: @MilanMarkovic it is in header.php

Comment: in the last line. and as the answer by Tai Le below mentions, you are not submitting any data before saving.

Comment: Actually it is not form. It is just a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you met the "confirm form resubmission" message. It happens when your user is not available. It directs to user/continueregistration, and you just redirect without refresh so then it sends data to datebase and continue redirect. To due with it, you should set: redirect('link', 'refresh'); and confirm a submit button, if it was clicked, then perform the actions inside.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])         //button with the name "submit"
{
    //action
}
```

Comment: Actually it is not form. It is just a page